# How to solve a system of quadratic equations?

Tags: quadratic-forms, real-algebraic-geometry, rootfinding

Suppose we have a system of $p$ quadratic equations about $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbf{x} > 0$

$$ \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
         \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{C}_1 \mathbf{x} = 1,  \\
         \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{C}_2 \mathbf{x} = 1,  \\
         \quad\quad \vdots\\
         \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{C}_p \mathbf{x} = 1,  \\
     \end{array}
    \right.$$

where matrices $\mathbf{C}_1, \dotsc, \mathbf{C}_p \in\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ are symmetric and positive definite.

Suppose $\mathbf{x} = [a,b,c]^\top$, and $\mathbf{y} = [a^2,b^2,c^2, ab, ac, bc]^\top$.  It is known that the above quadratic equations can be written as
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{Ay} = \mathbf{1},
\label{eq:linearsolver}
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times 6}$. If $p \geq 6$, we can obtain $\mathbf{y}$ and further estimate $\mathbf{x}$.

**Questions**:

1. Is there any methods besides $\mathbf{Ay}=\mathbf{1}$ to solve the above quadratic equations?
2. What is the minimal value of $p$ to guarantee a unique solution of $\mathbf{x}$ of the above quadratic system?

Comment: What do you mean by "What is the minimal value of $p$ to guarantee a unique solution"?  Do you mean the minimal value for which a solution *can* be unique?  No matter how big $p$ is, $\mathbf A$ could be, say, the $0$ matrix, in which case there are no solutions, or some low-rank matrix, in which case there could be multiple solutions.

Comment: If $\mathbf x$ is a solution then so is $-\mathbf x$, so you can't ever have uniqueness. Up to sign you can certainly recover $\mathbf x$ from $\mathbf y$ so the condition for having only _two_ solutions is indeed just that the matrix has full rank.

Comment: Have you tried in $\mathbb{R}^2$ first?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/308163

Comment: @LSpice Let's say $\mathbf{A}$ is always full rank in this case. I want to know how many quadratic equations are required to obtain $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$, is p=3 enough?

Comment: @lambda  I agree, from $\mathbf{y}$ to $\mathbf{x}$ there's a sign ambiguity even if $\mathbf{A}$ is full rank. Actually in my case $\mathbf{x} > 0$. I want to know whether there are other methods to solve quadratic equations?

Comment: X-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3764350/339790